# In Rails 4, how do I disable a button in a view and also ensure it cannot be clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, ruby-on-rails-4, view, link-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.  I want to disable a button and render it unclickable in my ERB, subject to certain conditions.  I tried this

```
    <%= link_to 'Submit Form', order_products_path, method: :post, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"},
                class: 'btn btn-class1', disabled: submit_disable %>
```

And although the button on the UI appears as disabled, it is still clickable (when I click on it, the "Are you sure?" confirmation appears).  So then I tried this

```
    <%= link_to_if !submit_disable, 'Submit Form', order_products_path, method: :post, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"},
                class: 'btn btn-class1', disabled: submit_disable %>
```

However now the button appears only as text.  What’s the proper way to disable a button and eliminate the ability for a user to click on it?

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_if` will return only name if the condition is false, however you could pass a block as falsy case, so, i think you could do like so

```rb
<%= 
 link_to_if !submit_disable, 'Submit Form', 
   order_products_path, method: :post, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, 
   class: 'btn btn-class1' do
     # disabled view
     label_tag 'Submit Form', nil, class: 'btn btn-class1'
 end
%>
```